# php $_SESSIONS passing variables

Tags: session, session-cookies, php

I have the following problem. I was using php sessions time ago and did not come to this. I tried to pass variables using $_SESSION. Everything was good until i have added some new vars.

i have this code in **page1.php**:

```
... 
if($count==1){
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$_SESSION = array();
$_SESSION['myusername']=$myusername;
$_SESSION['mypassword']=$mypassword;
$_SESSION['firstname']="someteststring"; //new added variable
$_SESSION['lastname']="someteststring"; //new added variable
?>
<script> // i put this following script just because i wanted
         // to see whats in session variables
    console.log(<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION); ?>);
</script>
<?
header("location:page2.php");
session_write_close();
...
```

After this i can see in firebug console all variables - when header function is commented :

```
firstname   "someteststring"
lastname    "someteststring"
mypassword  "password"
myusername  "username"
```

After **header** redirection (**page2.php**) i can see only two old variables  :

```
mypassword  "password"
myusername  "username"
```

And the **page2.php** is following :

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!(isset($_SESSION['myusername']))){
header("location:index.php");
}
echo $_SESSION['myusername'];
echo $_SESSION['mypassword'];
echo $_SESSION['lastname'];
echo $_SESSION['firstname'];
?>
```

Please note i have deleted also cached things from my browser, also cookies. Please can anybody help me? Maybe i forgot something.

Thank You.

Comment: Random guess: you're not actually starting the session on page1.php.

Comment: Have you got a session_start() on page1.php before you start trying to set session vars, are you unsetting unknown ones somewhere, without knowing the full code it is hard to know what may be up as the most likely causes are not in the section of code shown for page1

Comment: well guys this is really embarassing. I had ob_flush(); above session_start(); on the first line. Sorry for wasting your time. And thanks.

Comment: cookie contains the session reference once you deleted you can't get back " i have deleted also cached things from my browser, also cookies  "

Comment: Hello, can anybody explain me why is utf-8 encoding looks like headers was sent with <?php tag   ?? I had encoding issue so i switched it from utf-8 without BOM to normal utf-8. and headers - also session_start() throws error that headers cant be sent. Switchback helped.